# How to calculate weighted average of hourly sales in a day

Tags: statistics, average, means, descriptive-statistics

I have hourly sales data & want to aggregate it to a day level. Out of $24$ hours, we are classifying $6$ hrs as peak hours and $18$ hrs as non-peak.

Assume peak hr sales for a day as: $X_1, X_2,..., X_6$

Non-peak hr sales for a day as: $Y_1, Y_2,..., Y_{18}$

How can we take a weighted average of peak hr and non-peak hrs to get the data to a day level?

Comment: Take $\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} w_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_{i}}$

Comment: I suggest you ask this question in https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as that site is more focused on Statistics than this one.

Comment: @Shogun: The issue I'm facing is what to take as weights.

Comment: @NoChance: Thanks for the suggestion. I have posted the question in Stack Exchange.